# Problem Setting URLRequest Path

Tags: asp.net, flash

fla files which is calling default page . but it's not able to find the default page.. my default.aspx page is in root directory ,
and my fla file is in ../capture/image.fla . here is my code

```
function onSaveJPG(e:Event):void{
    var myEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(100);
    var byteArray:ByteArray = myEncoder.encode(bitmapData);

    var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

    var url:String = "../../default.aspx";

    var saveJPG:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    saveJPG.requestHeaders.push(header);
    saveJPG.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    saveJPG.data = byteArray;



    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendComplete);
    urlLoader.load(saveJPG);

    function sendComplete(event:Event):void{
        warn.visible = true;
        addChild(warn);
        warn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, warnDown);
        warn.buttonMode = true;
    }
```

Any pointer or suggestion how to set virtual path in flash??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest route is to use absolute paths instead of relative paths.
in your case you could do

```
var url:String = "/default.aspx";
```

Flash looks at paths from the point the swf file is included into the HTML so if your default.aspx is also serving the flash embed code the relative path would be  "default.aspx"

If you want to test while exporting from FLASH CS4 you will have to use a complete URL like

```
var url:String = "http://localhost/default.aspx"
```

I usually include this bit of code to make testing easier

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;

    ...
        var url:String = "/default.aspx";
        //test if playing in external player or in a browser
        if(Capabilities.playerType == "External") {
            url = "http://localhost"+url;
        }
    ...
```

Comment: trace(this.root.loaderInfo.loaderURL);  gives you the location of the swf.

Answer (score 1):

check using this...

```
var url:String = "~/default.aspx";
```